# Adding a rank value to my MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, rank

I have a fixed table that will not change. I have over 80,000 rows.

```
CREATE TABLE `word_list_master` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `word` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `frequency` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `number_of_files` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `combined_frequency` bigint(24) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I want to create a 7th column 'rank' that will determine the rank of the rows ordered by the combined_frequency column. I am doing this to reduce overhead when the database is live.

Can I do this via MySQL statement(s) or do I have to write a bunch of SELECT/INSERT statements in PHP (for example)? I have been doing most of the work so far in PHP but it is taking up to 24 hours to perform operations on the table.

I was looking at the RANK function but as my MySQL ability is only fair in capacity, I ran into problems.

Answer (score 2):

Normally I wouldn't consider "don't do this" to be a valid answer to such a question, but you're not going to help your situation by adding a new column. You already *have* a numeric column by which to order your data. Adding a second numeric column for this purpose is not only over-kill, it is bad design.

If it's taking "up to 24 hours" to do *any* operation on a table containing only 80,000 rows (which is not very many) then you need to [add indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) to the columns being used to search/sort/join.

Comment: If I am looking to select a row "WHERE rank = 5" for example, would it not be better to do this on a column that has already been predetermined? The table is static, it might not change even once within a year.

Comment: The correct way to do this is `select * from ... order by ... limit (5,1)`. This selects one row, offset five rows into the result set; that is, the 5th row from the ordered results. Once you've properly indexed your table, it will also be performant.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you add a `rank` field to your table:

```
 SET @rownum = 0; 

 SELECT *,  (@rownum := @rownum + 1) AS rank
 FROM word_list_master
 ORDER BY combined_frequency DESC;
```

**Update:** If you want to write queries against that rank field, you have to use the previous table as a derived table like so:

```
SET @rownum = 0; 
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT *,  (@rownum := @rownum + 1) AS rank
   FROM word_list_master
   ORDER BY combined_frequency DESC;
) t
WHERE rank = 5
```

And if you want to paging your query like so:

```
SET @rownum = 0; 
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT *,  (@rownum := @rownum + 1) AS rank
   FROM word_list_master
   ORDER BY combined_frequency DESC;
) t
WHERE rank BETWEEN ((@PageNum - 1) * @PageSize + 1)
AND (@PageNum * @PageSize)
```

**Update:**

Note that there is already a buit-in way to do this instead of this awful query which is the [`[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count }]`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html), which is the standard mysql-way to do this. Don't use the previous way if you just want to get a limited result set from your query.

Comment: Is there a way to permanently add the column 'rank' to the table?

Comment: Yes (by PHP), but its not faster

Comment: @Banners I think the `AUTO_INCREMENT` `id` in your table will work something like this. But why do you want to store the rank with in a field. it is not recommended. The order of the rows is insignificant in the relational model. You shouldn't consider the order of these data. You should think of your table as a set.

Comment: The table is static - it might change once a year, if that.

How would I select a row/rows from the table?

SET /@rownum = 0; 

 SELECT *,  (/@rownum := /@rownum + 1) AS rank
 FROM word_list_master WHERE rank= 5
 ORDER BY combined_frequency DESC;

That won't work - something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal **NO**. This is awful. You're re-implementing the offset clause. This is already built into MySQL.

Comment: @meagar - Sorry for that, He didn't mention that from the start of his question. He was looking for a ranking method. After that he asked to do that. I already added that. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks all - great answers and I can now plough on with my project.