# ORDER BY with CASE MySQL

Tags: mysql, count, sql-order-by, case

I have a "points standings" query, which shows statistics for a league I am in. I am attempting to order the query based off a few conditions.

1. If the team is ranked 1-25 in points, order by wins, points
2. If the team is ranked outside the top 25 (26th to 42nd in points), order by points.

The best way I could describe it, is that it should act like two tables. Teams ranked (1-25) should be sorted together, and teams ranked (26-42) should be sorted together.

Here is my query.

```
SELECT m.Team AS team
, SUM( r.points ) AS points
, SUM(CASE
    WHEN rank = 1 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS Wins
, SUM(CASE
    WHEN rank < 6 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS T5
, SUM(CASE
    WHEN rank < 11 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS T10
, SUM(CASE
    WHEN rank < 21 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS T20
, ROUND(Avg(r.points),2) AS ppr
, ROUND(Avg(r.rank),2) as avg_finish
, MIN(r.rank) as best
FROM members m
LEFT JOIN results r ON r.team_id = m.M_ID
GROUP BY team
ORDER BY 
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(*) < 26
        THEN Wins 
        WHEN COUNT(*) > 25
        THEN points
    END DESC, points DESC;
```

I receive an error "Reference 'Wins' not supported (reference to group function) due to my alias "Wins". Instead, I've tried:

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(*) < 26
        THEN SUM(CASE
            WHEN rank = 1 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END)  
        WHEN COUNT(*) > 25
        THEN points
    END DESC, points DESC;
```

This successfully orders my table, but does not factor the COUNT(*) > 25 CASE clause, and just orders by wins, then points. Any ideas on how I could refactor the ORDER BY clause?

Comment: The COUNT(\*) aggregate isn't giving a "row_number()" result. If you include the COUNT(\*) aggregate in the SELECT list, you'll see this... it's returning the count of rows for each team.  To identify the "top 25" or "first 25" rows, you'd need an analytic function like ROW_NUMBER(), which isn't available in MySQL. But it is possible to emulate that in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You should perform that `ORDER BY` in a outer query since the column alias `Wins` are not accessible in `ORDER` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT m.Team AS team
, SUM( r.points ) AS points
, SUM(CASE
    WHEN rank = 1 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS Wins
, SUM(CASE
    WHEN rank < 6 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS T5
, SUM(CASE
    WHEN rank < 11 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS T10
, SUM(CASE
    WHEN rank < 21 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS T20
, ROUND(Avg(r.points),2) AS ppr
, ROUND(Avg(r.rank),2) as avg_finish
, MIN(r.rank) as best
FROM members m
LEFT JOIN results r ON r.team_id = m.M_ID
GROUP BY team ) XXX
ORDER BY 
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(*) < 26
        THEN Wins 
        WHEN COUNT(*) > 25
        THEN points
    END DESC, points DESC;
```

Comment: Rahul, that query only returns one row (14th?). With an alert "This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available."

Answer (score 0):

The reference to `Wins` should be working.  MySQL accepts column aliases in the `order by`, so no subquery is necessary.

However, you might want the logic to be:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) < 26 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),  -- put the top ranking first,
         (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) < 26 THEN wins END) DESC,
         points DESC
```

In MySQL, you can also simplify the `select` logic:

```
SELECT m.Team AS team, SUM( r.points ) AS points,
       SUM(rank = 1) then Wins,
       SUM(rank < 6) as T5,
       SUM(rank < 11) as T10,
       SUM(rank < 21) as T20
       . . .
```

EDIT:

I think the `ORDER BY` you want is:

```
ORDER BY (points <= 26) DESC,  -- put the top ranking first,
         wins desc,
         points DESC
```

Comment: I still receive the error "#1247 - Reference 'wins' not supported (reference to group function)"

Comment: @JasonKarlavige . . .What version of MySQL are you using?  The very oldest versions (pre 5) don't allow aliases in the `order by`.

Comment: I am in phpMyAdmin, which is using version 5.5.45-cll-lve. Your SUM logic works for me by the way. Just an issue with the order by.

Comment: Hmmm . . . Something strange is going on.  The alias should really work.  Could you have hidden characters?  Or could there be a subtle misspelling?

Comment: My engines are InnoDB to allow the use of foreign keys, could that be an issue? I believe my issue is the way i'm attempting to order them. Is COUNT(*) < 26 the correct way to retrieve the first 25 rows?

Comment: @JasonKarlavige . . . Perhaps not.  `COUNT(*)` is going to return the number of rows for each team.  I don't know if that is what you mean by "first 25".

Comment: I'm attempting to get the top 25 teams ordered by points. If they're in the top 25 in points, then order by wins. It's kind of complicated. I'm currently doing it in Excel. I sort all 42 members by points to retrieve top 25 in points -> adjust table to top 25 -> sort top 25 by wins, points.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` is the number of rows for that team, not their rank.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support analytic functions like `ROW_NUMBER()` or `RANK()`.  If it did, we could make use of the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to identify the "first 25" rows based on a particular order. But there are a couple of approaches to emulating the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

One way would be to emulate it using a trick with user-defined variables. We'd use this approach is we needed to label the rows, and return the value.

In this case, we're only interested in whether a team is "in" the top 25 or not. So we could run a separate query that returns the "top 25" teams.

For example, this query gets *two* sets... a set results for "all teams" (`a`), and the set of the "top 25" teams (`t`), and matches those using an outer join operation:

```
 SELECT a.*
   FROM ( 
          SELECT m.team                   AS team
               , SUM( r.points )          AS points
               , SUM(IF( r.rank=1  ,1,0)) AS wins
               , SUM(IF( r.rank<6  ,1,0)) AS t5
               , SUM(IF( r.rank<11 ,1,0)) AS t10
               , SUM(IF( r.rank<21 ,1,0)) AS t20
               , ROUND(AVG( r.points ),2) AS ppr
               , ROUND(AVG( r.rank   ),2) AS avg_finish
               , MIN( r.rank )            AS best
            FROM members m
            LEFT
            JOIN results r
              ON r.team_id = m.m_id
           GROUP BY m.team
        ) a
   LEFT
   JOIN ( SELECT tm.team                   AS team    
               , SUM(IF( tr.rank=1  ,1,0)) AS wins
            FROM members tm
            LEFT
            JOIN results tr
              ON tr.team_id = tm.m_id
           GROUP BY tm.team
           ORDER
              BY SUM( tr.points ) DESC
               , SUM(IF( tr.rank=1  ,1,0)) DESC
               , tr.team_id DESC
           LIMIT 25
        ) t
     ON t.team = ta.team
  ORDER
     BY t.wins   DESC
      , a.points DESC
      , a.team   DESC
```

The inline view "a" is the query that gets all of the teams.

The inline view "t" is essentially the same query, but has an ORDER BY and LIMIT clause, so it returns at most 25 rows.  The ORDER BY gets applied before the LIMIT, so it will return the 25 teams that have the highest number of points. (Additional expressions are included in the ORDER BY to make the result more deterministic... if two teams that would be 25th and 26th in the list have the same number of points...

The outer query identifies which of the teams from `a` are in the "top 25", and applies the appropriate ordering.  (Note that teams that do not have matching rows from `t` will have NULL values for all of the columns from `t`... i.e. `t.wins` will be NULL, so the ORDER BY works.

We wouldn't necessarily need to return `wins` from the inline view `t`. We could just check if there was a matching row returned from `t` by testing for a NULL value.  e.g.

```
  ORDER
     BY IF(t.team IS NULL,NULL,a.wins) DESC
      , a.points DESC
      , a.team   DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you don't know the rank before you sort the result by `points`. If you would know the rank, you could sort with

```sql
ORDER BY (rank > 25) ASC
, CASE WHEN rank <= 25 THEN Wins ELSE 0 END
, points
```

One way to determine the rank in MySQL is to store the sorted result in a temporary table with an AUTO_INCREMENT rank column.

```sql
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_teams;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_teams (
    rank INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    team varchar(255),
    points INT,
    Wins INT,
    T5 INT,
    T10 INT,
    T20 INT,
    ppr INT,
    avg_finish INT,
    best INT
) AS
    SELECT null AS rank
    , m.Team AS team
    , SUM( r.points ) AS points
    , SUM(CASE
        WHEN rank = 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END) AS Wins
    , SUM(CASE
        WHEN rank < 6 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END) AS T5
    , SUM(CASE
        WHEN rank < 11 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END) AS T10
    , SUM(CASE
        WHEN rank < 21 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END) AS T20
    , ROUND(Avg(r.points),2) AS ppr
    , ROUND(Avg(r.rank),2) as avg_finish
    , MIN(r.rank) as best
    FROM members m
    LEFT JOIN results r ON r.team_id = m.M_ID
    GROUP BY team
    ORDER BY points DESC, Wins DESC, r.team_id ASC -- define the order for rank
;

SELECT *
FROM tmp_teams
ORDER BY (rank > 25) ASC
, CASE WHEN rank <= 25 THEN Wins ELSE 0 END
, points;
```

Another way is to use a session variable (@rank) which will be incremented in an ordered subquery:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT m.Team AS team
    , SUM( r.points ) AS points
    , SUM(CASE
        WHEN rank = 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END) AS Wins
    , SUM(CASE
        WHEN rank < 6 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END) AS T5
    , SUM(CASE
        WHEN rank < 11 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END) AS T10
    , SUM(CASE
        WHEN rank < 21 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END) AS T20
    , ROUND(Avg(r.points),2) AS ppr
    , ROUND(Avg(r.rank),2) as avg_finish
    , MIN(r.rank) as best
    , @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank
    FROM members m
    LEFT JOIN results r ON r.team_id = m.M_ID
    CROSS JOIN (select @rank := 0) AS init_rank
    GROUP BY team
    ORDER BY points DESC, Wins DESC, r.team_id ASC -- define the order for rank
    LIMIT 1000000000 -- workaround for some versions/settings to force sorting a subquery result
) sub
ORDER BY (rank > 25) ASC
, CASE WHEN rank <= 25 THEN Wins ELSE 0 END
, points
```

Answer (score 0):

It's finally working. Paul, you were in the right direction with ranking. Here is the link which Mahmoud provided the ranking I used:
[Rank Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675166/adding-a-rank-value-to-my-mysql-table)

```
SET @rownum = 0; 

SELECT *, (@rownum := @rownum + 1) AS chase FROM (
SELECT m.Team AS team
, SUM( r.points ) AS points
, SUM(r.rank = 1) AS Wins
, SUM(r.rank < 6) AS T5
, SUM(r.rank < 11) AS T10
, SUM(r.rank < 21) AS T20
, ROUND(Avg(r.points),2) AS ppr
, ROUND(Avg(r.rank),2) as avg_finish
, MIN(r.rank) as best
FROM members m
LEFT JOIN results r ON r.team_id = m.M_ID
GROUP BY team
ORDER BY points DESC ) AS ptotal
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN chase <= 24
    THEN Wins
END DESC, points DESC;
```

Thank you all for the help. I just recently started using this website and can't believe how helpful you all are. I know where to look when I have questions down the road!